# Get the memory address of a byref string reference

Tags: .net, vb.net, pointers

I am experimenting with more effective ways to generate forms. My experiments goes into the possibility to link strings, and other types, directly by their class reference and use it to update the original values without any strongly typed code.

I have been using GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject to get the memory address of the string, but it gives the the memory address of the string data, not the string class/reference that i need to change to allow me to use this approach.

I am aware that strings are immutable and can not be changed (Actualy, you can, but its not recomended), but I do not want to change the actual strings, but change the reference to it (the string object).

Is there some other way to get the address of a string object reference?

Some example code:

```
Private oTestperson As New Person

Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    ' Create the form
    AddText("Name", oTestperson.Name)
    AddText("Phone", oTestperson.Phone)
    AddText("Address", oTestperson.Address)

End Sub

Public Sub AddText(ByVal Title As String, ByRef sValue As String)

    Dim oGCHandle As System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle
    Dim oInputItem As New InputItem

    ' This does not do the job, as it only returns the address of the string data, not the reference to the string class
    oGCHandle = System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.Alloc(CType(sValue, Object), System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandleType.Pinned)
    oInputItem.Pointer = oGCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject()
    oGCHandle.Free()

    ' Store data
    oInputItem.ID = GetID()
    oInputItem.Type = InputTypes.Text
    oInputItem.BaseValue = sValue
    If Not Request.Form(oInputItem.ID) Then oInputItem.Value = Request.Form(oInputItem.ID)
    If oInputItem.Value Is Nothing Then oInputItem.Value = sValue

    ' Save in collection
    InputItems.Add(oInputItem)

End Sub

Private Sub linkbuttonSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles linkbuttonSave.Click
    Save()
End Sub

Public Sub Save()

    Dim oTest As New Person
    Dim oGCHandle As System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle
    Dim NewStrPointer As IntPtr

    ' Check if something has been changed, in that case update the origional value
    For Each oInputItem As InputItem In InputItems
        If oInputItem.Value <> oInputItem.BaseValue Then
            oGCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(oInputItem.Value, GCHandleType.Pinned)
            NewStrPointer = oGCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject()
            oGCHandle.Free()

            ' This fails as oInputItem.Pointer is the address of the string data, not the string class
            Marshal.WriteInt32(oInputItem.Pointer.ToInt32, NewStrPointer.ToInt32)

        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private InputItems As New ArrayList

Private Class Person
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Phone As String
    Public Property Address As String
End Class

Public Enum InputTypes As Integer
    Text = 0
End Enum

Public Class InputItem

    Public Property ID As String
    Public Property BaseValue As Object
    Public Property Value As Object
    Public Property Type As InputTypes = 0
    Public Property Pointer As IntPtr

End Class
```

Comment: So in essence you want the address of the pointer and not the address where the pointer points? So that you can direct the pointer to reference other strings by changing the address of the pointer? Am I missing something here?

Comment: There's more than one thing wrong here, the pointer you obtained is no longer pointing to a pinned object after you called GCHandle.Free().  If you want to write code like this then use C or C++.  C++/CLI is a nice language that lets you do both.

Comment: Correct, I want the address of the pointer, instead of the address of where the pointer points. My bad about the GCHandler.Free(). I tested without freeing the handler before. Looks like makeing a C++ "unsafe" dll is probably the only way to be able to do this then.

Answer (score 0):

The approved way to do this is using reflection, it will be much easier and the CLR will be able to ensure you are not trashing objects all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is a bit C++/VB6/late 90's, but 10 for the effort! :)

Read up on [System.Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx) for [iterating classes](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article132.aspx), [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w67sdsex.aspx) for binding (data)classes to GUI and [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx) for reading/writing classes. Using WPF will further simplify the task to near nothingness (Note WPF can be used in WinForms via [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx).

Comment: Yes, but that solution will not be as elegant as what I am trying to accomplish.