# How to get the memory address of a string in C#?

Tags: c#

Could someone show me the way to get the memory address of a `string` in C#? For example, in:

```
string a = "qwer";
```

I need to get the memory address of `a`.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: Why do you need the address? The framework is free to move it around at will under normal conditions...

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, getting the memory address of a variable is not the correct first step. Can you tell us what problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: Try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314453/get-the-memory-address-of-a-byref-string-reference.

Comment: string a =”abc”;
string b = a;
a = “def”;
console.writeline(b) ;  // abc    because now a and b refers to different two different memory address.

Comment: @DerrickJeevan How does that describe your problem?

Comment: @DerrickJeevan and why is that a problem for you?

Comment: @DerrickJeevan Strings in .NET are immutable. I think that's a thing you're missing.

Comment: no it is not problem. i just wanna check the memory address of a and b.

Comment: Don't do it in C# then.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek They are so much immutable that the old `StringBuilder()` built strings by doing `new String(' ', 10)` and then writing character-by-character :-)

Answer (score 7):

You need to fix the string in memory using the fixed keyword and then reference the memory address using char*

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Transform());
        Console.WriteLine(Transform());
        Console.WriteLine(Transform());
    }

    unsafe static string Transform()
    {
        // Get random string.
        string value = System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName();

        // Use fixed statement on a char pointer.
        // ... The pointer now points to memory that won't be moved!
        fixed (char* pointer = value)
        {
            // Add one to each of the characters.
            for (int i = 0; pointer[i] != '\0'; ++i)
            {
                pointer[i]++;
            }
            // Return the mutated string.
            return new string(pointer);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

**61c4eu6h/zt1

ctqqu62e/r2v

gb{kvhn6/xwq**

Answer (score 7):

Lets take the situation you are surprised about:

```
string a = "abc";
string b = a;
a = "def";
Console.WriteLine(b); //"abc" why?
```

`a` and `b` are references to strings. The actual strings involved are `"abc"` and `"def"`.

```
string a = "abc";
string b = a;
```

Both `a` and `b` are references to the same string `"abc"`.

```
a = "def";
```

Now `a` is a reference to a new string `"def"`, but we've done nothing to change `b`, so that is still referencing `"abc"`.

```
Console.writeline(b); // "abc"
```

If I did the same with ints, you should not be suprised:

```
int a = 123;
int b = a;
a = 456;
Console.WriteLine(b); //123
```

**Comparing references**

Now you understand `a` and `b` are references, you can compare those references using `Object.ReferenceEquals`

```
Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b) //true only if they reference the same exact string in memory
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call RtlInitUnicodeString. The function returns the length and address of the string.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct UNICODE_STRING
    {
      public ushort Length;
      public ushort MaximumLength;
      public IntPtr Buffer;
    }

  [DllImport("ntdll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
  static extern void RtlInitUnicodeString(out UNICODE_STRING DestinationString, string SourceString);

  [STAThread]
  static void Main()
  {
    UNICODE_STRING objectName;

    string mapName = "myMap1";
    RtlInitUnicodeString(out objectName, mapName);

    IntPtr stringPtr1 = objectName.Buffer;   // address of string 1


    mapName = mapName + "234";
    RtlInitUnicodeString(out objectName, mapName);

    IntPtr stringPtr2 = objectName.Buffer;  // address of string 2
  }
}
```

It can be useful to understand how C# manage strings.